# Firefox - animated gif on hover does not work twice

Tags: jquery, html, css

On hover I want to set a background-image to an animated gif with one loop. On mouseleave the initial background image is set. In Firefox the first time it is played everything works fine. On the second hover however the gif isn't played any more. Why?

html

```
 <div id="pic"><div class="su"></div></div>
```

js

```
        $( "#pic" ).hover(
              function() {
                $('.su').css({backgroundImage : 'url("ani.gif")'});
              }, function() {
                $('.su').css({backgroundImage : 'url("normal.jpg")'});
              }
            );
```

Comment: Why use jQuery for this?

Comment: `#pic .su { background-image : url("normal.gif"); } #pic:hover .su { background-image : url("ani.gif"); }`

Comment: @ChrisBurton your idea does not fix the problem

Comment: I wasn't presenting a solution.

Comment: @ChrisBurton tried your solution then it did not work twice in chrome as well

Comment: What solution? I only asked a question. Another person (@epascarello) posted that code.

Comment: Seems 100% fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/umccyf13/ Is there something up with your gif? Does it repeat?

Comment: Maybe some of the related questions on the right bar --> have a solution.

Comment: @epascarello your is looping forever thats why it is working. Yes I guess I have to remove and add the gif again.

Comment: @vuvu With an animated GIF that only animates once, it will only show the animation on the first hover, although it does show the static picture on subsequent hovers. Is that the problem? And you suggest that only Firefox does this, but Chrome has the same behaviour.